# Sugar ORM heritage of class and save elements android

Tags: android, sugarorm

I've a class like that :
`Person` which is the mother class : contains sex, age, name.

tow subclass :
`Student` and `Teacher`

I've saved differents students and teachers and I would like to get every Peron entities with code like that :
`Person.listAll(Person.class)`

But it doesn't work. i feel that Sugar doesn't understand the domain of heritage.

Any ideas ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Person> persons = Person.findAll(Person.class);
```

Will give you all Person records.